# Remove duplicate line only contain specific string

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I try to remove duplicates lines only if contain a specific string.
It's easy to remove only duplicates lines, but some useful lines is deleted with :

```
awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++'
```

Exemple :

keep first occurence of lines containing "host_name="
keep all occurrences of lines containing "plugin output="
with above `awk` or `Perl` commands that delete the client number too.

My output command :

```
host_name=Client1
plugin_output=Name : Client1 Marseille
host_name=Client1
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client1
host_name=Client1
host_name=Client1
host_name=Client1
host_name=Client1
host_name=Client1
host_name=Client1
host_name=Client2
plugin_output=Name : Client2 Besançon
host_name=Client2
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client2
host_name=Client2
host_name=Client2
host_name=Client2
host_name=Client2
host_name=Client2
host_name=Client2
host_name=Client2
host_name=Client3
plugin_output=Name : Client3 BRETAGNE
host_name=Client3
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client3
host_name=Client3
host_name=Client3
host_name=Client3
host_name=Client3
host_name=Client3
host_name=Client3
host_name=Client4
plugin_output=Name : Client4
host_name=Client4
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client4
host_name=Client4
host_name=Client4
host_name=Client4
host_name=Client4
host_name=Client4
host_name=Client4
host_name=Client5
plugin_output=Name : Client5
host_name=Client5
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client5
host_name=Client5
host_name=Client5
host_name=Client5
host_name=Client5
host_name=Client5
host_name=Client5
host_name=Client6
plugin_output=Name : Client6
host_name=Client6
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client6
host_name=Client6
host_name=Client6
host_name=Client6
host_name=Client6
host_name=Client6
host_name=Client6
host_name=Client6
host_name=Client7
plugin_output=Name : Client7
host_name=Client7
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client7
host_name=Client7
host_name=Client7
host_name=Client7
host_name=Client7
host_name=Client7
host_name=Client7
host_name=Client7
host_name=Client8
plugin_output=Name : Client8
host_name=Client8
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client8
host_name=Client8
host_name=Client8
host_name=Client8
host_name=Client8
host_name=Client8
host_name=Client8
```

Desired value after awk/sed/perl/...:

```
host_name=Client1
plugin_output=Name : Client1 Marseille
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client2
plugin_output=Name : Client2 Besançon
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client3
plugin_output=Name : Client3 BRETAGNE
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client4
plugin_output=Name : Client4
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client5
plugin_output=Name : Client5
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client6
plugin_output=Name : Client6
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client7
plugin_output=Name : Client7
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client8
plugin_output=Name : Client8
plugin_output=Client : 168131
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '/^plugin_output=/ || !seen[$0]++' file
host_name=Client1
plugin_output=Name : Client1 Marseille
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client2
plugin_output=Name : Client2 Besançon
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client3
plugin_output=Name : Client3 BRETAGNE
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client4
plugin_output=Name : Client4
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client5
plugin_output=Name : Client5
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client6
plugin_output=Name : Client6
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client7
plugin_output=Name : Client7
plugin_output=Client : 168131
host_name=Client8
plugin_output=Name : Client8
plugin_output=Client : 168131
```

Which prints a record if it starts with `plugin_output=` or if it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you're using is doing something slightly different to what you're trying to do.

In order to accomplish what you want - you're going to have to parse the current line.

```
perl -pe 'if ( my ($host) = m/host_name=(\w+)/ ) { next if $seen{$host}++; }'
```

Should the trick

Answer (score 0):

Perl version:

```
perl -ne 'print if !$seen{$_}++ || /^plugin_output=/'
```

or if you still want to use `unless` (I find `if` more readable in this case):

```
perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++ && !/^plugin_output=/'
```