# Remove duplicate line that contain an unknown string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

**file.txt**

```
test (CODE:700|SIZE:2356)
asdasdad (CODE:700|SIZE:124)
xcvxcva (CODE:700|SIZE:8974)
asdavasdasdasd (CODE:700|SIZE:124)
link-categories (CODE:700|SIZE:8974)
edit (CODE:700|SIZE:124)
```

I need command get all duplicated `SIZE:` value , then remove all duplicated lines have this value except one line, i mean the **output** should be like this:

```
test (CODE:700|SIZE:2356)
xcvxcva (CODE:700|SIZE:8974)
asdavasdasdasd (CODE:700|SIZE:124)
```

i found this command `sed '/SIZE:124/,+1 d' file.txt` in [Remove duplicate line only contain specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012885/remove-duplicate-line-only-contain-specific-string)

but this command removed all lines, what i need is remove duplicated lines except one line + this command will not search for duplicated `SIZE:` value, so it's not working!

**What i need is:**

- search for duplicated `SIZE:` value like `124` above!
- all lines have this value remove it, except one line or two line if you can.

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: `awk '!seen[$2]++' file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/SIZE:[0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);array[val]=$0;val=""} END{for(key in array){print array[key]}}' Input_file
```

OR adding a non-one liner form of solution:

```
awk '
match($0,/SIZE:[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  array[val]=$0
  val=""
}
END{
  for(key in array){
     print array[key]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/SIZE:[0-9]+/){              ##Using match function to match regex of SIZE: then digits in each line here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)       ##Creating variable val whose value is sub string of current line which has matched value from current line.
  array[val]=$0                       ##Creating an array named array with index of variable val and value is current line.
  val=""                              ##Nullify variable val here.
}
END{                                  ##Starting END block of this awk program here.
  for(key in array){                  ##Traversing through array here.
     print array[key]                 ##Printing array value here.
  }
}
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using this simple `awk` also:

```
awk -F '[ |]+' '!seen[$NF]++{print}' file
```

```
test (CODE:700|SIZE:2356)
asdasdad (CODE:700|SIZE:124)
xcvxcva (CODE:700|SIZE:8974)
```